# Word Automation Error - Server machine does not exists

Tags: excel, runtime-error, ms-word, vba

I am automating Word from Excel and use the following code. When i run the code first time I am always able to run it without issues. However, in the second instance I always get this error. Then I have to close the Word file manually and run the code again, it runs smoothly for the first time and I see the error again the second time.

[image]

```
'On Error Resume Next
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Dim intChoice As Integer
   Dim strPath As String
   Dim objWord As Object
   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   objWord.Visible = True
   Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
   intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
   If intChoice <> 0 Then
 'get the path selected
   strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
    msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
 'opens the document
  Set objdoc = objWord.Documents.Open(strPath)
  With Documents(objdoc)  '''This is where error points to in yellow '''
  Set myrange = ActiveDocument.Content
  ''' My execution code here 
  end with
  objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & 
  ActiveSheet.Range("E3").Value & "_MVR"
  'objWord.ActiveDocument.Close
  objdoc.Close
  objWord.Quit
  Set objdoc = Nothing
  Set objWord = Nothing      
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Since your code is no indented, you are "missing" the reson for your error. You are "releasing" the Word object `Set objWord = Nothing` inside the If statement `If intChoice <> 0 Then`. However, the `Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")` is created in anyway, just move `Set objWord = Nothing` outside the `If` and it will close the new **Word** instance you created.

Comment: I tried with the changes you suggested but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my notes above, try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutoWord()

Dim objWord As Object
Dim objdoc As Object
Dim intChoice As Integer
Dim strPath As String
Dim myRange As Range

'On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True

Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

If intChoice <> 0 Then
    'get the path selected
    strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)

    'opens the document
    Set objdoc = objWord.Documents.Open(strPath)

    With objdoc
        ' all your code related to opened Word document goes here

    End With
    objdoc.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("E3").Value & "_MVR"

    objdoc.Close
End If

objWord.Quit
Set objdoc = Nothing
Set objWord = Nothing

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: With Documents(objdoc) - I still get the error here.

Comment: @AbhinavBajpai when you run it in debug mode, at what line ?

Comment: In debug mode the code gives error at this line.   intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

Comment: I changed my code to objWord.Documents(objdoc) - now it works fine. Thanks for the effort.